# Symfony 2: New entity parameter not saving or returning null

Tags: php, symfony

I have added a new parameter to an entity but I am unable to save or have the values returned in retrieval. The parameter in the entity can be seen below with its getters and setters.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
protected $amount;

/**
 * Set amount
 *
 * @param decimal $amount
 *
 * @return Transaction
 */
public function setAmount($amount)
{
    $this->amount = $amount;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get amount
 *
 * @return decimal
 */
public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->amount;
}
```

I have created a migration and the new field has been added to the transaction table. When I attempt to save, a new record will be added but only the previously existing parameters will save, not $amount.

```
$this->addSql("ALTER TABLE transaction ADD amount NUMERIC(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL AFTER payment_method");
```

After not understanding why it wouldn't save I thought I'd update the database table directly to see if I could retrieve the manually. I set the amount value to `123.45` entered value with this:

```
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $transaction = $manager->getRepository('ShopHqCartBundle:Transaction')
        ->findOneByTransactionId($id);

    var_dump($transaction->getId());
    var_dump($transaction->getTransactionStatus());
    var_dump($transaction->getAmount());
```

All values apart from the new `amount`parameter work OK, but `getAMount()` returns `null`. If I update the `getAmount()` method to return `transactionStatus`, it will return the status OK. So the issue seems to be the declaration of the parameter in the entity but I can't see how or where.

```
public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->transactionStatus; // Return $transactionStatus as a test
}
```

I am also clearing the cache with `php app/console cache:clear`
. What am I missing in the entity preventing the new value to work as expected?

Comment: what var_dump($transaction->getAmount()); shows, null?

Comment: Yes, it shows null. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Have you try setting explicitly the precision for your decimal column ?

Comment: so do you have records in db with NOT NULL amount value?

Comment: @Yoann_Mir, the record in the database has been given a value which I expect to see when I dump it.

Comment: How do you fetch your object ? Can we see the query, is it a find ? a findBy or something custom ? also i was talking about setting precision in doctrine annotation like  @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)

Comment: Show us the code that saves object.

Comment: you haven't actually set a new value, as far as can be seen. so, it can be caused by you not properly setting the new value. (which is usually forgetting to call "flush" on the entity manager)